# Javascript: ES6: Функции. Параметры по умолчанию. Почему FOO2=70?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const FOO1 = (a = 20, b = a + 30) => {
  return a + b;
}
console.log("FOO1 = " + FOO1(undefined, 10));

const FOO2 = (c = FOO1()) => {
  return c;
}
console.log("FOO2 = " + FOO2());

let FOO3 = FOO1;
console.log("FOO3 = " + FOO3());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в функцию не передаете ни одного параметра. Значит, параметр `a` принимает значение по умолчанию `20`. Параметр `b` значение по умолчанию `а + 30 = 20 + 30 = 50`. Результат `a + b = 20 + 50 = 70`

```js
const FOO1 = (a = 20, b = a + 30) => {
  console.log("a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ", result=" + (a + b))
  return a + b;
}
console.log("FOO1 = " + FOO1(undefined, 10));

const FOO2 = (c = FOO1()) => {
  return c;
}
console.log("FOO2 = " + FOO2());
```

Comment: Все понял, я думал в случае с FOO2 FOO1 уже приняла значение 30. А она заново вызвалась с параметрами по умолчанию. Спс!

Answer (score 1):

У вас во втором вызове `FOO1()` принимает значение `70`, что не является удивительным, так как в этот раз ему не было задано значению по умолчанию для 2 аргумента.

```js
const FOO1 = (a = 20, b = a + 30) => {
  return a + b;
}
console.log("FOO1 = " + FOO1(undefined, 10));
console.log("FOO1 = " + FOO1());

const FOO2 = (c = FOO1()) => {
  return c;
}
console.log("FOO2 = " + FOO2());

let FOO3 = FOO1;
console.log("FOO3 = " + FOO3());
```